# Is this hadith regarding the wealth muslims are allowed to collect sahih?

Tags: source-identification

In tafseer ibn kathir, comments on following ayah includes an hadith which I would like to verify.

[image]

> **Sahih International**
>
> O you who have believed, indeed many of the scholars and the monks
>   devour the wealth of people unjustly and avert [them] from the way of
>   Allah . And those who hoard gold and silver and spend it not in the
>   way of Allah - give them tidings of a painful punishment.
>   [Surat At-Tawbah - 34](http://quran.com/9/34)

Following is the hadith which I would like to verify;

> Abdur-Razzaq recorded a Hadith from Ali about Allah's statement,
>
> وَالَّذِينَ يَكْنِزُونَ الذَّهَبَ وَالْفِضَّةَ
>
> (And those who hoard up gold and silver...) Ali said that the Prophet
>   said,
>
> « تَبًّا لِلذَّهَبٍ تَبًّا لِلْفِضَّة»
>
> (Woe to gold! Woe to silver.) He repeated this statement thrice, and
>   this Hadith was hard on the Companions of the Messenger of Allah , who
>   said, "What type of wealth should we use" Umar said, "I will find
>   out for you," and he asked, "O Allah's Messenger! Your statement was
>   hard for your Companions. They asked, "What wealth should we use"
>   The Prophet answered,
>
> «لِسَانًا ذَاكِرًا وَقَلْبًا شَاكِرًا وَزَوْجَةً تُعِينُ أَحَدَكُمْ
>   عَلَى دِينِه»
>
> (A remembering tongue, an appreciative heart and a wife that helps one
>   of you implement his religion.)
>
> Source: http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2561&Itemid=64

What is the grade of the above hadeeth? and what collection can I find it in?

Comment: There's a variation found in Tirmidhi (http://www.sunnah.com/urn/641030) which has apparently been graded Sahih by Al-Albani.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hadith is authentic / Saheeh it's sanad is:

> أخرج عبد الرزاق قال: أخبرنا الثوري قال أخبرني أبو حصين عن أبي الضحى عن جعدة بن هبيرة عن علي
>   رضي الله عنه

Source: [Tafseer Ibn Abbas...Page 455 Hadith 158](http://www.waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1686)

ِAs for which collection you can find it in, then you could find similar ahadeeth /Shawahid (شواهد) in many places, from Sunan Attirmidhi and Abi Dawood, to like Musnadu Ahmad.  As for the specific hadith you mentioned by Ali that was recorded by Abdur Razzaq, then I do not know where Abdur Razzaq has recorded it, I looked at his Mussannaf and his tafseer, and although I found something similar to the hadith in his tafseer but not with the above sanad.

If he had recorded it in his Musannaf then it might not be there as the original book [may not exist](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12778/9).  The closest hadith I could get in the Musannaf with the above mentioned sanad [was this](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-13174/page-12705#page-12705).

Comment: The last link (http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-13174/page-12705#page-12705) is not working. Can you kindly update it?