# Where did Abdul Razzaq (عبد الرزاق بن همام الصنعاني) record what Ali said in regards to those who hoard gold and silver?

Tags: source-identification

I have been researching to answer [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-this-hadith-regarding-the-wealth-muslims-are-allowed-to-collect-sahih) which asks about the grade of a hadeeth from Ali in regards to what Allah said:

> Abdur-Razzaq recorded a Hadith from Ali about Allah's statement,
>
> وَالَّذِينَ يَكْنِزُونَ الذَّهَبَ وَالْفِضَّةَ
>
> (And those who hoard up gold and silver...) Ali said that the Prophet
>   said,
>
> « تَبًّا لِلذَّهَبٍ تَبًّا لِلْفِضَّة»
>
> (Woe to gold! Woe to silver.) He repeated this statement thrice, and
>   this Hadith was hard on the Companions of the Messenger of Allah , who
>   said, "What type of wealth should we use" Umar said, "I will find out
>   for you," and he asked, "O Allah's Messenger! Your statement was hard
>   for your Companions. They asked, "What wealth should we use" The
>   Prophet answered,
>
> «لِسَانًا ذَاكِرًا وَقَلْبًا شَاكِرًا وَزَوْجَةً تُعِينُ أَحَدَكُمْ
>   عَلَى دِينِه»
>
> (A remembering tongue, an appreciative heart and a wife that helps one
>   of you implement his religion.)

In my search, I found [(In this book, page 455-6)](http://www.waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1686) that the sanad of this hadith is:

> ***(أخرج عبد الرزاق)***
>
> أخبرنا الثوري قال أخبرني أبو حصين عن أبي الضحى عن جعدة بن هبيرة عن علي
>   رضي الله عنه
>
> Athawri told us, Abu Husain told me from Abi Duha frp, Ju'da bin
>   Haibara from Ali (May Allah be pleased with him)

So with the above in mind, I looked at Abul Razzaq's [Mussannaf](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=60) and his [Tafseer](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=59), but I could not find the exact above hadith.  Now I do not know if I am missing something, but my question is where exactly did Abdur Razzaq record the above mentioned Hadeeth?

Answer (score 2):

You have not missed something. In fact this hadith cannot be found in any of available writings of Abul Razzaq himself. But other writers like Ibn Kasir have narrated this hadith from him.

The only record from himself containing the keywords mentioned in the question is this record:

In the book Al-Musnaf (المصنف) this hadith was found from Abul Razzaq:

> باب كم الكنز ؟ ولمن الزكاة ؟ 7150 - عبد الرزاق عن الثوري عن أبي حصين
>   عن أبي الضحى عن جعدة بن هبيرة عن علي بن أبي طالب قال : أربعة آلاف درهم
>   فما دونها نفقة ، وما فوقها كنز .
>
> المصنف - عبد الرزاق الصنعاني - ج 4 ص 109

This hadith is about the amount of wealth. So Abul Razzaq has narrated from Ali Ibn Abi Talib that four thousands of Dirham. So ay amount under it is Nafaqah (cost) and what above it is Kanz (treasure/wealth).

Al-Musnaf, Abul Razzaq Al-Sanaani, volume 4, page 109

But others like Ibn Kasir in his tafseer has narrated this hadith from him:

> قال عبد الرزاق أخبرنا الثوري أخبرني أبو حصين عن أبي الضحى عن جعدة بن
>   هبيرة عن علي رضي الله عنه في قوله ( والذين يكنزون الذهب والفضة ) الآية
>   قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم تبا للذهب تبا للفضة يقولها ثلاثا قال فشق
>   ذلك على أصحاب رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وقالوا فأي مال نتخذ فقال
>   عمرو رضي الله عنه أنا أعلم لكم ذلك فقال يا رسول الله إن أصحابك قد شق
>   عليهم وقالوا فأي مال نتخذ قال لسانا ذاكرا وزوجة تعين أحدكم على دينه

**Reference:**

Tafseer Ibn kasir, vol 2, page 352, publish: Dar al-Fikr, Beirut, 1401

Also some references say this hadith is narrated also by Sahaba other than Ali Ibn Abi Talib:

> وروي أيضا من حديث علي رواه عبد الرزاق في تفسيره أخبرنا الثوري أخبرني
>   أبو حصين عن أبي الضحى عن جعدة بن هبيرة عن علي رضي الله عنه في قوله
>   تعالى ) والذين يكنزون الذهب والفضة ولا ينفقونها في سبيل الله ( فقال
>   النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ( تبا للذهب تبا للفضة ) يقولها ثلاث قال فشق
>   ذلك على أصحاب رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وقالوا أي مال نتخذ قال (
>   لسانا ذاكرا وقلبا شاكرا وزوجة تعين أحدكم على دينه )
>
> انتهى
>
> الحاصل أنه حديث ضعيف لما فيه من الإضطراب

---

**Reference:**

تخريج الأحاديث والآثار الواقعة في تفسير الكشاف للزمخشري ، اسم المؤلف:  جمال الدين عبد الله بن يوسف بن محمد الزيلعي الوفاة: 762هـ ، دار النشر : دار ابن خزيمة - الرياض - 1414هـ ، الطبعة : الأولى ، تحقيق : عبد الله بن عبد الرحمن السعد، ج 2   ص 71

Comment: Nothing was removed or changed in "newer publishes" just because it was narrated by Imam Ali.  I have found the above hadith way before I asked the question, but the hadith in quetsion is what Ali said in regards to the Ayah: 
"وَالَّذِينَ يَكْنِزُونَ الذَّهَبَ وَالْفِضَّةَ", which I did find a similar one in his tafseer but not by Imam Ali, so I was confused to find the same sanad but for a different hadith, that is why in my question I said I don't know whether I am missing something.   But currently your answer does not address my question.

Comment: @AlUmmat answer improved. I hope it be useful. also I suggested checking remove or change only as a possibility because I have seen many of such case.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Musannaf of Abd ar-Razzaq tahqiq by Habib ar-Rahman al-Azami version of Shamilah #7150

The problem with this book was that it has been mixed up and parts of it lost within other books. The original manuscript I THINK doesn't actually exist.

So it took a lot of research from other books, 20 years to be exact, by Habib ar-Rahman to finally compile the Musannaf that was by Abd ar-Razzaq.